# Why visual studio 2012 debugger resumes

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I'm wondering if anyone has seen this behavior (and know how to fix it):

When debugging with visual studio 2012 Update 1, the debugger just resumes execution randomly when stepping into (like if you press F5 or hit play). I've used many visual studio versions and this is the first time that I'm seing this happening.

This is local debugging, no service or remote debugging, just plain old local single threaded winform. My symbols are fully loaded and up to date, the option "just my code" is disabled, I've cleaned and rebuilded the solution.

This is pretty annoying so any input will be appreciated.

Comment: What does "resumes execution randomly when stepping into" mean? If you're *stepping into* you're executing; did the debugger or you application stop at some point?  (which is implied by "resumes").

Comment: @PeterRitchie Sorry if that wasn't clear, it means the debugger stops debugging and that the program being debugged resumes it's execution (as if you press F5 while debugging). Really weird

Comment: This was a problem in VS2008 SP1 and again in VS2010 RTM, both fixed with hotfix/service pack.  I haven't heard it being an issue in VS2012.  You'll need to take this to the people that can fix this, post to connect.microsoft.com.  You'll need to do a much better job documenting your problem than you did here or they'll quickly close your feedback with "no repro".  So be sure to include a small repro project that exhibits this problem with repro steps.  Call Microsoft Support if you don't want to wait.

Comment: @HansPassant I was curious and I reinstalled VS2010 to test what you said. I confirm that you are right, I tried debugging the project in 2010 RTM and the same problem occured but it didn't after I installed sp1.